# CSS para impressão - Como controlar o fluxo de dados

Tags: html, css, print

Boa tarde!
Estou montando um layout para impressão, onde haverá uma quantidade de dados que ultrapassa mais de uma página.

Alguém sabe como controlar a quantidade de dados por página para não cortar os dados no final do documento?

A idéia da impressão é ser realizada no `window.print()` em um html independente.
Atualmente tentei com o css, assim:

```
@page{
    size: A4;
    margin: 5mm 6mm 2mm 6mm;
    page-break-after: always;
}
```

Mas ao chegar no final da página, fica cortando os dados e seguindo para próxima página... gostaria de conseguir controlar para que a quebra de página acontecesse antes de cortar.

No layout tenho o html nessa idéia:

```
    <meta charset="utf8">

<style>
body{
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#e8e8e8;
}
@page{
    size: A4;
    margin: 5mm 6mm 2mm 6mm;
    page-break-after: always;
}
.box_container{
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:left;
    width: 793px;
    height: 1122px; 
}
.box{
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    padding:10px 0 10px 0;
    border-bottom:1px solid #e8e8e8;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
.box li{
    display:inline-block;
    width:99%;
    padding:0 0 0 1%;
}
.box_title{
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000000;
    padding:20px 0 20px 0;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
</style>

<div class='box_container'> 

  <div class='box_title'>Título</div>

  <div class='box'>
    <li>Rótulo: 1</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 2</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 3</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 4</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 5</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 6</li>
  </div>

   <div class='box'>
    <li>Rótulo: 1</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 2</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 3</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 4</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 5</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 6</li>
  </div>

   <div class='box'>
    <li>Rótulo: 1</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 2</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 3</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 4</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 5</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 6</li>
  </div>

   <div class='box'>
    <li>Rótulo: 1</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 2</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 3</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 4</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 5</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 6</li>
  </div>


   <div class='box'>
    <li>Rótulo: 1</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 2</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 3</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 4</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 5</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 6</li>
  </div>

   <div class='box'>
    <li>Rótulo: 1</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 2</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 3</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 4</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 5</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 6</li>
  </div>

   <div class='box'>
    <li>Rótulo: 1</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 2</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 3</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 4</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 5</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 6</li>
  </div>

   <div class='box'>
    <li>Rótulo: 1</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 2</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 3</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 4</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 5</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 6</li>
  </div>

   <div class='box'>
    <li>Rótulo: 1</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 2</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 3</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 4</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 5</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 6</li>
  </div>

   <div class='box'>
    <li>Rótulo: 1</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 2</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 3</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 4</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 5</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 6</li>
  </div>

   <div class='box'>
    <li>Rótulo: 1</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 2</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 3</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 4</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 5</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 6</li>
  </div>

   <div class='box'>
    <li>Rótulo: 1</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 2</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 3</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 4</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 5</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 6</li>
  </div>

   <div class='box'>
    <li>Rótulo: 1</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 2</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 3</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 4</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 5</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 6</li>
  </div>

   <div class='box'>
    <li>Rótulo: 1</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 2</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 3</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 4</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 5</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 6</li>
  </div>

   <div class='box'>
    <li>Rótulo: 1</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 2</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 3</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 4</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 5</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 6</li>
  </div>

   <div class='box'>
    <li>Rótulo: 1</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 2</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 3</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 4</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 5</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 6</li>
  </div>

   <div class='box'>
    <li>Rótulo: 1</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 2</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 3</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 4</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 5</li>
    <li>Rótulo: 6</li>
  </div>





</div><!-- /box_container -->  

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script>
    $(".box_container").click(function(){
        window.print();
    });//end click
  </script>
```

Quando a página está acabando e o resultado é o 4 por exemplo, atualmente fica o 4 numa página e o 5,6 noutra. O certo seria pular o bloco inteiro, de 1 a 6 para página seguinte... alguém saberia como?

Vou colocar uma imagem aqui para demonstrar o que ocorre:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5TnZ.jpg
[image: img demonstração]

Comment: Acho que isso vai te dar uma Luz! https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/373300/pagina-para-imprimir-1-ou-2-colunas-html/387913#387913

Comment: tentei colocar no box esse css:     -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    column-fill: balance;
        column-count: 2;
        -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
          page-break-inside: avoid;
               break-inside: avoid;

Comment: ele cria colunas de outra forma, etc... mas nas limitações da página não resolveu, continuar o msmo corte no final...

Comment: Cara esses dias devo estar sem PC, mas assim que der vou fazer uns testes, se vc puder edite sua resposta com parte do seu conteúdo real, e fala onde esta cortando, assim fica mais fácil pra gente simular o seu problema

Comment: Bom dia! Adicionei uma imagem demonstrando o que ocorre.

Comment: Editei a pergunta com o código html/css que pode ser testado e visualizado o que ocorre;

Comment: Agora que tive um tempo pr ver isso, mas acho que vai resolver seu problema, depois da uma olhada na resposta, seu código tinha alguns detalhes, mas agora está funcionando!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu código tinha alguns probleminhas, tipo limitar uma altura pro `box_container` com um `height` e colocar nele `display:inline-block`. Tirando essas propriedade e colocando a propriedades abaixo eu consegui controlar a quebra dos blocos de conteúdo.

```
        -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
        page-break-inside: avoid;
        break-inside: avoid;
```

Repare nesse imagem como nenhum bloco de conteúdo se quebra, sempre o `item 6` está no final da página.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title>Page Title</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <style>
  body {
   text-align: center;
   background-color: #e8e8e8;
  }

  .box_container {
   /* display: inline-block; */
   text-align: left;
   width: 793px;
   /* height: 1122px; */
   -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
   page-break-inside: avoid;
   break-inside: avoid;
   margin: 0 auto;

  }

  .box {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
   padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
   background-color: #FFFFFF;


  }

  .box li {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 99%;
   padding: 0 0 0 1%;
  }

  .box_title {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
   padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
   text-align: center;
   background-color: #FFFFFF;
  }

  @media print {
   @page {
    size: A4;
    margin: 5mm 6mm 2mm 6mm;
    page-break-after: always;
   }
  }
 </style>
</head>

<body>
 <div class='box_container'>

  <div class='box_title'>Título</div>

  <div class='box'>
   <li>Rótulo: 1</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 2</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 3</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 4</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 5</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 6</li>
  </div>

  <div class='box'>
   <li>Rótulo: 1</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 2</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 3</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 4</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 5</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 6</li>
  </div>

  <div class='box'>
   <li>Rótulo: 1</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 2</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 3</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 4</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 5</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 6</li>
  </div>

  <div class='box'>
   <li>Rótulo: 1</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 2</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 3</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 4</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 5</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 6</li>
  </div>

  <div class='box'>
   <li>Rótulo: 1</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 2</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 3</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 4</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 5</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 6</li>
  </div>

  <div class='box'>
   <li>Rótulo: 1</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 2</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 3</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 4</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 5</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 6</li>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, quos quas impedit temporibus ea tempore
   dicta ratione totam odit nulla voluptatem pariatur. Accusantium cum impedit vitae excepturi voluptate, amet
   ea.
  </div>

  <div class='box'>
   <li>Rótulo: 1</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 2</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 3</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 4</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 5</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 6</li>
  </div>

  <div class='box'>
   <li>Rótulo: 1</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 2</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 3</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 4</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 5</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 6</li>
  </div>

  <div class='box'>
   <li>Rótulo: 1</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 2</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 3</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 4</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 5</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 6</li>
  </div>
  <div class='box'>
   <li>Rótulo: 1</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 2</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 3</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 4</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 5</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 6</li>
  </div>

  <div class='box'>
   <li>Rótulo: 1</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 2</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 3</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 4</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 5</li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas porro modi aliquam debitis,
   beatae quo aspernatur corrupti, accusamus recusandae veritatis quae suscipit quidem consequuntur sint
   voluptas rerum veniam architecto vitae.
   <li>Rótulo: 6</li>
  </div>
  <div class='box'>
   <li>Rótulo: 1</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 2</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 3</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 4</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 5</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 6</li>
  </div>

  <div class='box'>
   <li>Rótulo: 1</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 2</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 3</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 4</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 5</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 6</li>
  </div>
  <div class='box'>
   <li>Rótulo: 1</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 2</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 3</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 4</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 5</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 6</li>
  </div>

  <div class='box'>
   <li>Rótulo: 1</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 2</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 3</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 4</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 5</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 6</li>
  </div>
  <div class='box'>
   <li>Rótulo: 1</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 2</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 3</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 4</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 5</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 6</li>
  </div>

  <div class='box'>
   <li>Rótulo: 1</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 2</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 3</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 4</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 5</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 6</li>
  </div>
  <div class='box'>
   <li>Rótulo: 1</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 2</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 3</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 4</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 5</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 6</li>
  </div>

  <div class='box'>
   <li>Rótulo: 1</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 2</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 3</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 4</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 5</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 6</li>
  </div>
  <div class='box'>
   <li>Rótulo: 1</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 2</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 3</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 4</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 5</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 6</li>
  </div>

  <div class='box'>
   <li>Rótulo: 1</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 2</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 3</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 4</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 5</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 6</li>
  </div>
  <div class='box'>
   <li>Rótulo: 1</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 2</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 3</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 4</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 5</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 6</li>
  </div>

  <div class='box'>
   <li>Rótulo: 1</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 2</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 3</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 4</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 5</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 6</li>
  </div>
  <div class='box'>
   <li>Rótulo: 1</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 2</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 3</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 4</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 5</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 6</li>
  </div>

  <div class='box'>
   <li>Rótulo: 1</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 2</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 3</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 4</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 5</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 6</li>
  </div>
  <div class='box'>
   <li>Rótulo: 1</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 2</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 3</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 4</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 5</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 6</li>
  </div>

  <div class='box'>
   <li>Rótulo: 1</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 2</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 3</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 4</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 5</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 6</li>
  </div>
  <div class='box'>
   <li>Rótulo: 1</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 2</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 3</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 4</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 5</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 6</li>

  </div>

  <div class='box'>
   <li>Rótulo: 1</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 2</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 3</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 4</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 5</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 6</li>
  </div>
  <div class='box'>
   <li>Rótulo: 1</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 2</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 3</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 4</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 5</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 6</li>
  </div>

  <div class='box'>
   <li>Rótulo: 1</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 2</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 3</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 4</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 5</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 6</li>
  </div>
  <div class='box'>
   <li>Rótulo: 1</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 2</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 3</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 4</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 5</li>
   <li>Rótulo: 6</li>
  </div>






 </div><!-- /box_container -->

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 <script>
  $(".box_container").click(function () {
   window.print();
  }); //end click
 </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Perfeito! Com essa implementação a quebra ocorre corretamente no final da página. Obrigado!!!

Comment: @Neo legal, que bom que deu certo ai []´s